# fix xpath name business not read in silenium

Tags: python-3.x

i have a problem where i can't retrieve the business name on google maps,
html google maps picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkCtC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL5xS.png)
my script :

```
for index, listing in enumerate(new_listings):
                try:
                    listing.click()
                    page.wait_for_timeout(10000)

                    name_xpath = '//div[contains(@class, "qBF1Pd fontHeadlineSmall ")]'
                    address_xpath = '//button[@data-item-id="address"]//div[contains(@class, "fontBodyMedium")]'
                    website_xpath = '//a[@data-item-id="authority"]//div[contains(@class, "fontBodyMedium")]'
                    phone_number_xpath = '//button[contains(@data-item-id, "phone:tel:")]//div[contains(@class, "fontBodyMedium")]'
                    reviews_span_xpath = '//span[@role="img"]'

                    business = Business()

                    # Click on the name element to ensure only that data is loaded
                    name_element = page.locator(name_xpath).nth(index)
                    name_element.click()
                    page.wait_for_timeout(2000)  # Adjust the timeout as needed

                    # Extract business information
                    business.name = name_element.inner_text()
                    business.address = (
                        page.locator(address_xpath).inner_text()
                        if page.locator(address_xpath).count() > 0
                        else ""
```

i need fix name xpath for google maps